# Filter all email using plus addressing

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-search

I am looking for a way in gmail (technically google apps for business I think) to filter all email which is delivered to an address using plus addressing. I want to tag all email to `firstname.lastname@example.com` as one thing and `firstname.lastname+[anything at all here]@example.com` as something else.

I was intrigued to discover that whilst searches for `firstname.lastname+test-1@example.com` only returned messages to that specific address, searches for `firstname.lastname@example.com` included all plus addressed messages in the results, which seems slightly inconsistent, but I assume is by design.

As far as I can tell what I'm trying to do isn't possible, due to the lack of support for wildcard searches, but I thought I would check that there isn't another way to do it. I don't think this question is a duplicate of any of the following, but if anyone feels that it is, I'm sorry and feel free to shut this down.

The question [How can I filter incoming email based on plus addressing in Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2593/how-can-i-filter-incoming-email-based-on-plus-addressing-in-gmail) notes that you can filter a specific plus address eg `firstname.lastname+test-1@example.com`.

The question [Wildcard search in Gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2433/wildcard-search-in-gmail) notes that there is no real support for wildcard searches in gmail filters.

The question [Filter email based on Gmail plus operator, with wildcard](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/101510/filter-email-based-on-gmail-plus-operator-with-wildcard) seeks to use a wildcard search to filter a set of plus addresses eg

- `firstname.lastname+test-1@example.com`
- `firstname.lastname+test-2@example.com`
- `firstname.lastname+test-3@example.com`.

And concludes that this is not possible. I think my question is different as I am attempting to filter *all* plus addresses messages, rather than a set of them, however I suspect that the answer to my question is no for the reasons listed here.

Comment: not possible in gmail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to shut this down definitively, this does not seem to be possible in Gmail currently.

Answer (score 0):

This answer from another StackExchange question seems to work.

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/126613/304879

Comment: I'm not sure why this has been downvoted; I can confirm that this does work. The solution (as given in the linked question) is to drop the @ symbol from the search, so for example: `to:"firstname.lastname example.com"`. This will only return results for the base address without returning any plus address aliases.